# Accessing NSMutableDictionary inside NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary` (it's a plist). Each dictionary in the array has 2 keys: '`id`' and '`lu`'.

How can I find the index in `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary` where, for example, `id` = '47653'?

I tried to do it but it's not working:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSString *path = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"id.plist"];
NSMutableArray *mut_array = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];

NSMutableDictionary *mut_dico = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *egalIDPlistData = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"id"];

for(mut_dico in mut_array) {
    if([[mut_dico objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"47653"]) {
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need this: `= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`

Comment: Hint:  `NSLog(@"My array is %@", mut_array);` will nicely format the array of dictionaries so you can be sure what you have.

Comment: Are you sure the dictionary entries are strings and not, say, NSNumbers?

Comment: @HotLicks I do it `NSMutableDictionary *mut_dico = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`
I'm sure that the dictionary entries are NSString.

Comment: The NSLog display: `My array is (
        {
        id = 49711;
        lu = 1;
    }
)`

Comment: The fast enumeration is just stomping your alloc'd dictionary. It doesnt need it, this is a dictionary pointer only.

Comment: That 49711 value is a NSNumber, not an NSString (no quotes).

Comment: Like I said, you don't need `= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The objects in the loaded plist are not mutable.

Try:

```
for(NSDictionary * dict in mut_array)
{
    if([[dict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"49711"]) {
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray *mut_array = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];` will create a mutable array of immutable dictionaries, not mutable dictionaries. `mutableCopy` is not a deep copy.

Regardless of mutability, the following will do what you want:

```
NSUInteger indexOfDictionary = [[array valueForKey:@"id"] indexOfObject:@"49711"];

if(indexOfDictionary == NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"no matching objects found!");
    return;
}

NSDictionary *fullDictionary = [array objectAtIndex:indexOfObject];
```

The `valueForKey:` uses the fact that a key-value coding call on an array returns an array of the results of that call on each object in the array, in the same order, and the fact that `NSDictionary` will respond similarly in this situation to both `valueForKey:` and `objectForKey:`

As for the issue of whether what you're really dealing with is strings or numbers, try using just `@49711` in place of `@"49711"` and if that works instead you've got numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In your log id is 49711 & in  your if condition it is 47653. Your condition will not satisfy until there is dictionary in your array with id = 47653